# how to write a trigger on account object if the existing record then update some fields accordoing to you else create a new Records?

Tags: salesforce

how to write a trigger on account object(salesfroce) if the existing record then update some fields according to you else create a new Records ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using `upsert`?  It allows you to either insert record or update if it already exists. `insert` and `update` in a single, smart command.
You want to update record, and if it does not exist, create new one.
With `upsert` you can first try to obtain record (if nothing found, create new instance), then set your fields up, and finally, upsert it.

Like:

```
Account myAcc;
try {
    myAcc = [ SELECT Id, Name FROM Account where Id='someIdImLookingFor'];
    myAcc.Name = 'My desired name';
catch (Exception e) {
    myAcc = new Account(Name='My desired name');
}
upsert myAcc
```

Answer (score 0):

'Upsert' is the best way to do that. If the record is present it helps you to update the record else create a new one.

```
Account[] acctsList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity FROM Account WHERE BillingCity = 'Bombay'];
 for (Account a : acctsList) {
    a.BillingCity = 'Mumbai';
}
Account newAcct = new Account(Name = 'Acme', BillingCity = 'San Francisco');
  acctsList.add(newAcct);
try {
   upsert acctsList;
} catch (DmlException e) {
  // Process exception here
}
```